# How to Create a sprite Image

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

I am trying to create a very basic sprite image.

First off i have an existing image (Width=100px, Height=100px).

I will be looping through this image between 10 and 100 times, each time placing it on the sprite next to the previous one.

The sprite is limited to 3000px wide.

Placing the images next to each other is fine, cause i can just combine them with a simple method, however, i need to limit the width of the combined images to 3000px, then start on a new line.

Comment: Sounds simple enough; loop the image appending while the length of the total image is less than 3000px.

Comment: http://stylemeltdown.com/image-sprite-navigation-with-css/

Comment: that's what i though, but as you can see, i have to start on a "new line" when the sprite is a total of 3000px wide.

Comment: Hi @DustyRoberts, am I on the right track regarding your question?

Comment: sorry about the un-clear question, I was not referring to sprite's as gam developers knows it, but rather image sprites as web devs and html guys knows it. @Matt, you have a complete answer so the bounty went to you, but daniel, I marked your's as the answer, as you actually got what I was asking:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try with some pseudocode:

```cs
Bitmap originalImage; //  that is your image of 100x100 pixels
Bitmap bigImage;      //  this is your 3000x3000 canvas
int xPut = 0;
int yPut = 0;
int maxHeight = 0;
while (someExitCondition) 
{
    Bitmap imagePiece = GetImagePieceAccordingToSomeParameters(originalImage);
    if (xPut + imagePiece.Width > 3000)
    {
        xPut = 0;
        yPut += maxHeight;
        maxHeight = 0;
    }
    DrawPieceToCanvas(bigImage, xPut, yPut, imagePiece);
    xPut += imagePiece.Width;
    if (imagePiece.Height > maxHeight) maxHeight = imagePiece.Height;
    //  iterate until done
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a lot of information about 2D-sprites in the following MSDN article: [Rendering 2D sprites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff634505.aspx)

Those examples are based on [Microsoft's XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA), which is a platform that can be used within Visual Studio to develop games for Windows, Windows Phone and XBOX 360.

For example, to draw a sprite, you can use the following C# code (example taken from the MSDN article, XBOX 360 specific code removed):

```
private Texture2D SpriteTexture;
private Rectangle TitleSafe;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        SpriteTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");
        TitleSafe = GetTitleSafeArea(.8f);
    }

    protected Rectangle GetTitleSafeArea(float percent)
    {
        Rectangle retval = new Rectangle(
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.X,
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Y,
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
        return retval;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        Vector2 pos = new Vector2(TitleSafe.Left, TitleSafe.Top);
        spriteBatch.Draw(SpriteTexture, pos, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

You need to call `LoadContent()` to initialize it, then you need to call `GetTitleSafeArea(100)` to get the safe draw area (in this case wich 100 percent), finally you can use the `Draw` method. It accepts a parameter containing an instance of the `GameTime` class, which is a Snapshot of the game timing state expressed in values that can be used by variable-step (real time) or fixed-step (game time) games.

Please let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Hi Matt, it's customary in StackOverflow answers to include a summary of the contents of a link or the highlights that specifically answer the question. The goal of SE sites is to become a resource of knowledge, of answers, for years to come. With a link-only answer, the op must dig through another resource to locate an answer he/she might not be sure about. Most importantly, if your link were to ever break (often Microsoft ones do over time), your answer is useless for anyone who visits this page in the future. Consider making and edit to your answer to add more details. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I agree and thus I have added more details. Regards, Matt

Answer (score 2):

declare a variable at 3000, if you put in a picture of width 250 take that away from the variable, keep doing this, this also allows you to decide if there is enough space left on that line for your next picture by seeing if the number left is larger than the width of the next picture. every time you start on a new line set the variable back to 3k and start again. solved

Answer (score 2):

An approach that can work is by allowing to place the sprite's frames anywhere in the bitmap (that way you can make them more compact) and accompany each bitmap with a(n xml) file that describes the location, size and origin of each frame AND has a listing of all the animations. Something like this:

```xml
<SpriteSheet>
    <Frames>
        <Frame id="0" location="20,40" size="64,64" origin="32,32" />
        <Frame id="1" location="100,40" size="64,64" origin="32,32" />
        <Frame id="2" location="164,40" size="64,64" origin="0,0" />
        <Frame id="3" location="20,120" size="64,64" origin="32,32" />
    </Frames>
    <Animations>
        <Animation name="walk left" >
            <Keyframes>
                <Keyframe frameId="0" duration="0:0:0.5" offset="-5,0" />
                <Keyframe frameId="1" duration="0:0:0.5" offset="-5,0" />
                <Keyframe frameId="2" duration="0:0:0.4" offset="-2,0" />
                <Keyframe frameId="1" duration="0:0:0.5" offset="-5,0" />
            </Keyframes>
        </Animation>
        <Animation name="walk right" >
            <Keyframes>
                <Keyframe frameId="5" duration="0:0:0.5" offset="5,0" />
                <Keyframe frameId="6" duration="0:0:0.5" offset="5,0" />
                <Keyframe frameId="2" duration="0:0:0.4" offset="2,0" />
                <Keyframe frameId="6" duration="0:0:0.5" offset="5,0" />
            </Keyframes>
        </Animation>
    </Animations>
</SpriteSheet>
```

This way you can re-use frames across animations (and so optimizing the bitmap sizes even more) and customize the animations by simply editing the XML file.

All you have to do is read the XML file, read the bitmap and when starting an animation: start a timer that ticks at a regular interval. When it ticks you calculate the correct Keyframe in the animation by adding the durations of the Keyframes one by one and stopping when the sum is more than the tick time; the current Keyframe should be used.

In the XML file above I added stuff such as an offset that allows you to modify the position of the sprite during the animation (you could even interpolate it so it moves smoothly)

All that is left is grabbing the correct frame out of the bitmap. As an optimization you could pre-process the bitmap when loading the XML file by grabbing the frames, keeping those as tiny bitmaps, and discarding the big bitmap. This might optimize memory when the bitmap is big and not fully covered in frames.

In other cases, you don't pre-process and just blit the frame.

For larger applications (more bitmaps/animations/frames) I recommend creating an app to create and edit the XML file. Another option might be to create a plugin for your favorite paint program (if possible)