# How to return several images using a byte array?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello someone helped me to return several images, works perfect to bring the first since I'm using `FirstOrDefault`.

This function from the controller and the portion of razor

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Detalle(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Item item = await db.Items.Include(i => i.Imagenes).Where(p => p.ProductoID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (item == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(item);
}

public ActionResult RenderImage2(int id)
{
    Imagen imagen = db.Imagenes.Where(i => i.ProductoID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    byte[] photoBack = imagen.InternalImage;
    return File(photoBack, "image/png");
}
```

Here Razor:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Imagenes)
{
    <li>
        <a class="thumb-item-link" data-slide-index="0" href="">
            <img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage2", new { id = Model.ProductoID})" alt="img" />
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: the problem is that always shows me the first picture, if I have three pictures, showing me the first three times.

Comment: Then you need to tell your `RenderImage2` which of the images to render, probably with another parameter...

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, what kind of parameter should happen?

Comment: Let's start over, because I think this is an XY Problem. [edit] your question to show how `Imagen` is defined. There may be a way of doing this with a lot less code.

Comment: apology, is that I speak Spanish, I'm doing everything possible to write in English. So how could improve this? changing the way we store the image?

Comment: Hmm... You might be interested in [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/). I'd follow you over, but my Spanish stopped at about "Donde esta el autobus?" :)

Comment: Jaja, it happens that in  stack overflow español community is small and not help asking why I prefer here.

Comment: If you know a different way to store images that can be displayed and then you appreciate the example.

Comment: Well, if all of the Spanish speaking programmers keep coming over here, it won't get any larger... :). I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!!! I just had to change the product ID by the ID of the image in both the controller and the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return more than one image in the same Action as it only returns a single file, but you can generate an image sprite that contains all the images and return it as a single file but in this case your client has to understand that it is expecting an image sprite not an image

Comment: I understand, and as I do that? an example? Thank you.

Comment: check this, it has your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451823/how-to-create-a-sprite-image

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have a unique ID for each `Imagen` (named `ImagenID` for the sake of this example).

So your method would look like:

```
public ActionResult RenderImage2(int id)
{
    Imagen imagen = db.Imagenes.Where(i => i.ImagenID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    byte[] photoBack = imagen.InternalImage;
    return File(photoBack, "image/png");
}
```

Since each `Imagen` has a unique ID, that should only return the image you want.

In your Razor, you'd just use the `item` you're already tracking:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Imagenes)
{
    <li>
        <a class="thumb-item-link" data-slide-index="0" href="">
            <img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage2", new { id = item.ImagenID })" alt="img" />
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

That's assuming `Model.Imagenes` contains `Imagen` objects which come from the same place as `db.Imagenes`.

Comment: I am a fool! haha had to change just that.
I worked through that.
Greetings from Argentina :)

Comment: No problema. Do check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for how Stack Overflow works with answers.

Comment: I voted as correct reply but apparently did not have enough reputation to display to the public: |